# Eclipse Library is not showing

Tags: android, eclipse

I m using the eclipse for android development. and i updated the api of android. and now all the project is showing the error. i have attached and image and i m not able to add library [image]

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I'd suggest migrating to Android Studio. I found eclipse corrupted my projects pretty much every time I upgraded the SDK and the simplest solution was a complete reinstall. Since migrating the project to AndroidStudio I've not had any issues

Comment: it happened to me twice... i finally decided not to update library only..but install whole new Eclipse with latest SDK

Answer (score 0):

go to your library right click and go properties and then android and check Is Library

[image: look picture]